# Создание WAR посредством Maven

Tags: java, intellij-idea, maven, компиляция, war

Моя задача собрать приложение в WAR-архив. Имею следующий `pom.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.modularplatform</groupId>
    <artifactId>ModularPlatform</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>9.0.10</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <outputDirectory>build/</outputDirectory>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources/</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>*</include>
                    <include>s/*</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/webapp/</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>*</include>
                    <include>WEB-INF/*</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <attachClasses>true</attachClasses>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>war</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

После компиляции в директории `build/` нет war-архива. Что я делаю не так?

P.S. Использую InteliJIdea

Comment: А вы, надеюсь, собираете командой `mvn package` ?

Comment: @ArchDemon я собираю из InteliJ Idea. Я не знаю, что она вызывает

Comment: В консоли вывода может быть вывод команды на сборку. Так, например, делает netbeans

Comment: @ArchDemon нету.

Comment: @wcobalt тогда вам стоит добавить idea в теги и упомянуть об этом в тексте вопроса.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev добавил

Comment: @wcobalt Покажи stack trace ошибки.

Comment: @VladimirGlinskikh ошибок нет.

Comment: @wcobalt Как ошибок нет, у тебя же помник красный?! Странно все это.

Comment: @VladimirGlinskikh почему красный, светится зеленым.

Comment: @wcobalt Так пересобери вопрос тогда. В вопросе  у тебя помник красный.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IJ при компиляции не собирает war файлы. Собирать нужно с помощью запуска цели package в окне проектов Maven или же с помощью командной строки

```
mvn package
```

из корневой папки проекта.

Кстати команду можно запускать не выходя из среды если открыть терминальное окно.

Comment: А можно ли это повесить на кнопочку Build Project?

Comment: Где находится такая кнопочка?

Comment: вот тут https://ibb.co/g3UGkp