# Запуск Spring проекта без Main класса

Tags: java, spring, maven, tomcat, ide

Изучаю Spring, начал писать приложение по гайдам других людей.
Вроде всё понятно что к чему там работает но вот только есть у меня один нераскрытый вопрос.
Есть проект Spring, система сборки Maven.
архитектура папок src/main
/java/myProject - здесь весь Java код.
/resource/db.properties - здесь файлы настроек и xml
/WEB-ИНФ/page.jsp - здесь файлы для WEB формы (Прошу прощения за ИНФ на английском не смог написать, т.к. сайт принимает это как часть кода, а как оформить правильно я не знаю.....)

Работаю в IDE IntelliJ Ultimate. Через run/edit Configuration подключил к проекту локальный репозиторий с TomCat 9.0. Проект запускается просто по нажатию кнопки запуска в IDE и выбранном методе запуска TomCat сервер (он автоматом появился), т.е. у меня нет в проекте класса с которого стартует проект - public static void main(String[] args){}.

Как мне собрать проект в .war, ведь в папке META-ИНФ в файле MANIFEST.MF не будет ссылки на класс запуска?

Comment: https://developer.okta.com/blog/2019/04/16/spring-boot-tomcat - следуй за желтым котиком

Comment: Вот [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/866793/204920) можно почитать как это можно сделать.

Comment: Спасибо Сергей, но немного не то. И тебе Роман спасибо, но я уже разобрался в задаче.

Answer (score 0):

Запускаем package в меню maven/lifecycle
появляется папка в target-те с именем вашего проекта и версией снапшота.
!!! В .war упаковывать проект не нужно !!! Папку с нашим проектом просто перемещаем
в сервер Tomcat в папку webapps и запускаем наш сервер.
Наш проект доступен по ссылке http://localhost:8080/nameProject
И еще небольшое дополнение, если имя папки проекта слишком большое, то просто сократите название папки, и имя после http://localhost:8080/ тоже сократится.